# Iterative closest points algorithm with three.js buffer geometry objects

Tags: three.js, geometry, augmented-reality, point-clouds

I have two meshes similar to each other in terms of shape I want to align these two meshes as a perfect fit as a source and target method used in ICP, what are the best methods we can use in three.js to do this? both are the points array their default positions and rotations are 000.

[These are my two meshes/ point clouds:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgNx0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to solve the Kabsch algorithm, there is an implementation [here](https://zalo.github.io/blog/kabsch/).